# Understanding physically correct lighting in three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm probably mis-understanding something but... I'm trying to use physically correct lighting and physically based rendering in three.js

I made a simple scene. In this case just a plane. I put a light 2 units (2 meters) above the plane. The plane is using a `MeshStandardMaterial` with `roughness` at .9 and `metalness` at 0. The light's `power` is set to 800 which if I understand correctly is 800 lumens which is equivalent to a 60 watt light bulb. I set `renderer.physicallyCorrectLights = true`.

Here's the result:

[image]

That result looks nothing like a 60 watt light bulb 2 meters above a floor.

Am I doing something wrong?

```js
'use strict';

/* global dat */

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvas});
  renderer.physicallyCorrectLights = true;

  const fov = 45;
  const aspect = 2;
  const zNear = 0.1;
  const zFar = 100;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);
  camera.position.set(0, 10, 20);
  camera.lookAt(0, 5, 0);

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color('black');

  {
    const planeSize = 40;
    const planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(planeSize, planeSize);
    const planeMat = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
      color: '#C84',
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
      roughness: 0.9,
      metalness: 0,
    });
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, planeMat);
    mesh.rotation.x = Math.PI * -.5;
    scene.add(mesh);
  }

  {
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 1;
    const light = new THREE.PointLight(color, intensity);
    light.power = 800;
    light.decay = 2;
    light.distance = Infinity;
    light.position.set(0, 2, 0);
    scene.add(light);
    
    const helper = new THREE.PointLightHelper(light);
    scene.add(helper);
  }

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render() {

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
  render();
  window.onresize = render;
}

main();
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#c {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/96/three.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 4):

When doing physical scenes you have to take exposure (f-stop) settings into account. I can't find a dedicated settings for the camera to allow this (which perhaps would be a natural place to find it), but there is an exposure setting for the renderer itself -

You could play around with the [`toneMappingExposure`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.toneMappingExposure) settings on the renderer to find a good value, for example:

```
renderer.toneMappingExposure = Math.pow(0.7, 5.0);  // -> exposure: 0.168
```

and for example a more real-world value for power:

```
light.power = 740;  // GE Lumens @ 60W incandescent
```

[image: result]

A technical consideration: Watts cannot be directly translated into Lumens simply because different brands produce different Lumens values at the same Wattage; they can actually vary roughly between 400-1000 Lumens in the case of 60W incandescent lights (GE operates with 740 or so). But that's a side-point.. :)

```js
'use strict';

/* global dat */

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvas});
  renderer.physicallyCorrectLights = true;

  renderer.toneMappingExposure = Math.pow(0.7, 5.0);
  
  const fov = 45;
  const aspect = 2;
  const zNear = 0.1;
  const zFar = 100;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);
  camera.position.set(0, 10, 20);
  camera.lookAt(0, 5, 0);

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color('black');

  {
    const planeSize = 40;
    const planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(planeSize, planeSize);
    const planeMat = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
      color: '#C84',
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
      roughness: 0.9,
      metalness: 0,
    });
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, planeMat);
    mesh.rotation.x = Math.PI * -.5;
    scene.add(mesh);
  }

  {
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 1;
    const light = new THREE.PointLight(color, intensity);
    light.power = 740;  // GE Lumens @ 60W incade.
    light.decay = 2;
    light.distance = Infinity;
    light.position.set(0, 2, 0);
    scene.add(light);
    
    const helper = new THREE.PointLightHelper(light);
    scene.add(helper);
  }

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render() {

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
  render();
  window.onresize = render;
}

main();
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#c {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/96/three.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know where I can find more info about exposure? Why ^5? Why is .7 a reasonable exposure? Etc... If the point of PBR is we put in real world values and get real world results then I'd like to understand where these values are coming from.

Comment: Sorry, the 0.7 should have been 0.168. The pow is I guess to make the demo slider produce a logarithmic result which seem natural when moved around (I see I forgot to link to the demo it was taken from). For real-life values you would have to use not only f-stop, but also shutter-speed, ISO, film-size, indirect lighting etc. Typically EV (Exposure Value, f-stop+shutter) or Lux is used in a real-life scenario for [relative] exposure, I'm not sure how to convert that to the exposure settings in three though, I suspect it may be a bit arbitrary.